# Create SAS for Azure storage in JavaScript (PhoneGap)

Tags: javascript, azure, cordova

I am creating a PhoneGap application that utilizes Azure Mobile Services. I have data uploading and downloading without an issue. Now I want to take a picture on the phone and upload it to Azure Blob Storage. I've done some research and it looks like I need to do the following:

1. Create a shared access signature (SAS)
2. Use XMLHttpRequest to upload the file
3. Associate that file with a record in SQL (via Mobile Services)

Step two seems rather straightforward, since I don't have to worry about CORS. Step three seems like it should be rather straightforward as long as the return from the upload gives me some type of identifier. The other possibility is that I generate a unique name for the file before uploading it. The real issue is step one. How do I generate a SAS?

I've looked over the answers on StackOverflow and Google and I have seen a lot of examples. However, they all seem to deal with C# or they assume I am in the browser (and thus the CORS issues). Since I am going to be running natively, what do I do?

So, my questions are:

1. How do I generate a SAS? Do I have to create a web service just for this? If so, is there one I can download quickly and just use?
2. Are my assumptions correct about #2 and #3? Are there good examples that you know of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using Mobile Services, you already got a web service (after all, mobile service is a back end service). What you would need to do is write some code there which will return you SAS. You could either use node.js or C# to write that code. For an example, see here: [`Upload images to Windows Azure Storage by using Mobile Services`](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-windows-phone-upload-data-blob-storage/). This example, essentially creates a SAS in Mobile Service and returns back to the client. Client can then take it and upload image into blob storage.

You may find this link useful for PhoneGap and Azure Mobile Service Integration: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-javascript-backend-phonegap-get-started/.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. I had actually seen that article before but I was in that haze of "too many non-related articles" and missed that even though it says C#, it actually works for what I want to do. Thanks so much.